# Why does useEffect only working properly once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, setstate

I'm having big problems that are getting me hella confused with React useEffect & States.

I have this following component, everything in it looks to work normally until I redirect to my app main page and try it again.
The problem is that the useEffect is triggered once and do not work anymore even if the server is sending infos correctly as I already Tested. Going to show a video for example

```js
const GameComponent = function(props) {
    const [selectedHand, setSelectedHand] = useState('random')
    const [isGameReady, setIsGameReady] = useState(false)
    const [gameStep, setGameStep] = useState(0)
    let listenersStarted = useRef(false)
    function currentSelector(e){
        setSelectedHand(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('value'));
    }


    function getSelectedHand(value) {

        if (value === selectedHand) {
            return "box3 selected";
        }
        return "box3";
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        const serverInteractions = {

            sendChoice: ()=>{
                props.server.emit("choice", selectedHand)
            },

            startListeners: ()=>{

                props.server.emit("game status")
                if (!listenersStarted.current){
                    if (!props.server.hasListeners('game status')){
                        props.server.on('game status', async args=>{
                            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 250));
                            document.getElementById('instruction').textContent = args['status']
                            setIsGameReady(args['isReady'])
                        })

                        props.server.on('game result', async ()=>{
                            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 250));
                        })

                    }
                    listenersStarted.current = true
                }
            }
        }

        serverInteractions.startListeners()

    }, []);



    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isGameReady, gameStep)
        if (isGameReady && gameStep===0){
            setGameStep(1)
        }else if(!isGameReady && gameStep>0){
            setGameStep(0)
        }
    }, [isGameReady]);
    useEffect( () => {

        const asyncFunction = async ()=>{

            if(!isGameReady && gameStep >0){
                await setGameStep(0)
            }else if (isGameReady){
                console.log(gameStep, isGameReady)
                if (isGameReady && gameStep === 1){
                    document.getElementById('instruction').textContent = ""
                    const oldGameStep = gameStep
                    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));

                    if (isGameReady && oldGameStep == gameStep){
                        await setGameStep(2)

                    }
                }else if(isGameReady && gameStep === 2){
                    console.log('mandando resultado')
                    //await serverInteractions.sendChoice()
                    document.getElementById('instruction').textContent = ""


                }else if(isGameReady && gameStep===3){
                    console.log(isGameReady)
                    if (isGameReady){
                        console.log(isGameReady)
                        document.getElementById('instruction').textContent = ""
                        setSelectedHand('random');
                        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));
                        if (isGameReady){
                            await setGameStep(0)

                        }
                    }

                }else if(isGameReady && gameStep===0){
                    await setGameStep(1)

                }

            }

        }
        asyncFunction()
    }, [gameStep]);
```

Video:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oGfz.jpg

Video 2 ( With more server informations )
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm00v.jpg

As you can see In this video, I do the step by step until I get the problem. First I join into a room then the useEffect seems to work normally but when trying again after a SPA redirect to the main page and doing the same thing it stops working, only triggering once. I'm sure that the server is sending the same infos correctly, and don't see many reasons to it not work ( the gameIsReady is a boolean value, and the server is returning false/true )

This is the highlight of useEffect:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isGameReady, gameStep)
        if (isGameReady && gameStep===0){
            setGameStep(1)
        }else if(!isGameReady && gameStep>0){
            setGameStep(0)
        }
    }, [isGameReady]);
```

And this is were setState is used:

```js
props.server.on('game status', async args=>{
                            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 250));
                            document.getElementById('instruction').textContent = args['status']
                            setIsGameReady(args['isReady'])
                        })
```

Already tried:
Adding isReady and gameStep to dependencies

Comment: as per the video, second time you are getting ```isGameReady=false``` and ```gameStep=0```, it wont match the if and else if conditions, so no change will happen.

Comment: What is `props.server`? Given you're registering _"on"_ callbacks, should you also de-register them in your [component's cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)?

Comment: @gvmani I think you got it wrong, when I joined the room isGameReady=false and gameStep are by default false and 0, the room I joined got an other socket connected too and server was returning true to say that the game is ready to start, it was setting state to true ( i confirmed this by console logging the infos ) but useEffect wasn't working, thats the problem.

Comment: @Phil props.server is inherited from another component that is hosting this one, and is from the Socket.io thing. And I can try unregistering those callbacks but I don't think it's going to work since they are always giving me the correct informations so the game can start but useEffect only works once.

Comment: @Phil After trying what you said I managed to solve the problem, was something very simple but yeah, thanks!

Comment: You should answer this question below with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De-registering your socket.io listeners is the answer.